How to find a string in a range and sum all the values inside multiple brackets for that string within a single cell in Google Sheets?
I am trying to find a particular string in a specific range of cells and the sum of the values that are inside the brackets following that particular string and storing the same in another table.
For Example, In Sample Sheet
I am trying to find the string Food in the range C3:C33 and add the values inside the brackets 200,100,150,55,150,120 in Table 1 and store their sum 775 in Table 2.
I wondered if this could be automated using a formula.

Table 1




A
B
C




Date
Day
Details


01-01-2022
Saturday
Food(200)+Parking(50)


07-01-2022
Friday
Food(100)+Shopping(500)+Travel(100)


08-01-2022
Saturday
Shopping(200)


10-01-2022
Monday
Food(150)+Travel(90+25)


15-01-2022
Saturday
Food(55)+Shopping(88)+Parking(73)


18-01-2022
Tuesday
Food(150)


22-01-2022
Saturday
Food(120)+Movies(300)+Parking(80)


28-01-2022
Friday
Parking(120)


31-01-2022
Monday
Movies(250)




Table 2




G
H




Spending Area
Total


Food
775


Travel
215


Movies
550


Parking
323


Shopping
788




If there were only a number in parentheses, then a formula like =SUM(ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(VALUE(REGEXEXTRACT(C3:C33,G3&"\((\d+)")),0))) would do the job. But a string like "Travel(90+25)" spoils everything. Is it important for you to see just such an entry in brackets?

=QUERY(
   BYROW(
     INDEX(
       SPLIT(
         TOCOL(
           REGEXREPLACE(
             SPLIT(C3:C33,")"),
             "^[+-]",),
           1),
         "(")), 
     LAMBDA(x, IF(LEN(INDEX(x,,1)),
       {INDEX(x,,1), 
          SUM(
            SPLIT(
              " "& 
                REGEXREPLACE(
                  ""&INDEX(x,,2), "([+-])",   "$1"),
              ""))},))), 
   "Select Col1, SUM(Col2) Where Col2 > 0 Group By Col1 Label Col1 'Category'")  

